# Chances of seeing 5 losses in a row if chance of loss is (1/8) and you play 4,320 times?

Tags: probability, statistics

Say you are playing a completely random game. You have a (7/8) chance to win, and a (1/8) chance to lose.

What are the chances that you would lose 5 times **in a row?**, if you played the game 4,320 times?

What is the formula for this?

Comment: What will help you here is Markov chains. I have an old answer for a variation of this problem somewhere on the site.

Comment: You mean lose 5 times in a row at least once or exactly once? Either way Markov chains will help you but one case is a bit more complicated than the other.

Comment: @mathreadler At least once. And thank you for helping me out.

Comment: $\frac{1}{8}^5=\frac{1}{32768}$, maybe that'd help....?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2214416/213607 here is one practical method, you just need to exchange the values in the matrix with 1/8 on the "stairs" and 7/8 along the edge. The $k$ value you raise the matrix to is $4320$ and the number of steps of the stairs is the number of loss in a row.

Comment: I'm new to these concepts, so I will need time to figure out how to calculate this even though you gave me the setup to do so.